# What is the use of fit method in sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer()?

Tags: scikit-learn, normalization

According to the documentation of fit(self, X[, y]) method of sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer(), it does nothing and return the estimator unchanged.
I understand that if I intend to normalize data I can simply pass the data to the Normalizer() function. so what is the use of use of fit method. Moreover, normalization is not a learning algorithm so why is there a fit() method?

Answer (score 3):

In scikit-learn, many preprocessing operations follow the Estimator API (i.e. having `fit` and `transform` methods).  The benefit of conforming to the Estimator API is that the object can be included in a [data transformation pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/data_transforms.html).  Some of the benefits of pipelines are described in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators):

> Pipeline can be used to chain multiple estimators into one. This is useful as there is often a fixed sequence of steps in processing the data, for example feature selection, normalization and classification. Pipeline serves multiple purposes here:
>
> **Convenience and encapsulation**:
>   You only have to call fit and predict once on your data to fit a whole sequence of estimators.
>
> **Joint parameter selection**:
>   You can grid search over parameters of all estimators in the pipeline at once.
>
> **Safety**:
>    Pipelines help avoid leaking statistics from your test data into the trained model in cross-validation, by ensuring that the same samples are used to train the transformers and predictors.

Because the Normalizer estimator is stateless, its `fit` method is a no-op.  But if it was missing the `fit` method, then it could not be used in scikit-learn Pipelines.